# Atomic operations in CUDA supported by specific GPU

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, nvidia, atomic, gpu

I have wrote a program in CUDA which will be executing on GPU (nvidia geforce 310m). In kernel I've used atomicMin function. After compiling and running I have got an error: "Kernel execution failed : <8> invalid device function". I think that may be due to the fact that my card does not support atomic operations. Am I right or there is some other thing to consider? By the way to run the atomic operations I've read that I need to change in visual studio: Project properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Device -> Code Generation -> compute_13,sm_13. Thanks.

Comment: WhatGPU are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your GPU does not match the compute architecture (`sm_13`) you are compiling for.

The description of error code 8 in `driver_types.h` is as follows:

```
/**
 * The requested device function does not exist or is not compiled for the
 * proper device architecture.
 */
cudaErrorInvalidDeviceFunction        =      8,
```

A typical reason for this is that the compiled binary architecture does not match the device architecture.  You don't mention which GPU you are using, but I'm guessing it's not a `sm_13` device.

You can determine what GPU device you have and it's compute architecture and capabilities by running the cuda [deviceQuery sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#utilities).

More specifics about the compute architecture required for various atomic operations can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions).  Note that some atomic functions are available as early as the `sm_11` (compute 1.1) architecture, including some versions of the `atomicMin` function.

**EDIT:** based on the fact that you're now indicating your GPU is a GeForce 310m device, this is not a compute 1.3 capable device.  Therefore specifying `sm_13` won't work.  Your [GeForce 310m is a compute 1.2 device](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus), so if you specify that architecture (sm_12) you should be able to run code that has been successfully compiled that way.

Regarding atomics, compute 1.2 devices do support certain atomic operations, including certain versions of `atomicMin`.  Since you haven't shown your code, I can't say anything beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

CUDA devices with compute capability 1.3 support atomic operations. Try compiling your code with the following flag

```
 -arch sm_13
```

Comment: As I've said I am using visual studio and I've changed  Project properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Device -> Code Generation -> compute_13,sm_13. So I think this is not a solution.